# Docker container doesn't start because of "task: non-zero exit (1)" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up the nginx proxy on my Amazon AWS Docker instance together with a pimcore instance. This is my compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:  
  nginx-proxy:
    image: codesuki/ecs-nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  pimcore-jcii:
    image: ****/pimcore5:current
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    links:
      - "db"
    volumes:
      - efs-storage:/data
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

volumes:
  efs-storage:
    driver: cloudstor:aws
    driver_opts:
      backing: shared
```

If I deploy this stack the nginx proxy container can not start. It appears the following error message:

```
task: non-zero exit (1)
```

I've got the error message by "docker inspect ".

What am I doing wrong? Or where can I gather more informations about the state of the container?

Comment: did you check if you have the same behaviour on your local docker?

Comment: I met the same question, I extant memory limits for service and that is work for me. so try using like : deploy: resources: limits: memory: 256m add service memory.